# looping issue in laravel

Tags: laravel, loops, controller, laravel-blade

i have two tables which one has room and other has bed when room table enter no of bed 4 then it will other bed table bed four time entry for 4 beds

then i want make every bed own modal so how to do it

i m little confuse for how to do it

here is my code

```
  $room = new Room(array(
    'floor_id'=>$request->get('floor_id'),
    'room'=>$request->get('room'),
    'bed_type'=>$request->get('bed_type'),
    'no_of_beds'=>$request->get('no_of_beds'),
    'status'=>'assign'
));
$room->save();
$id = $room->no_of_beds;
for($i=1; $i<=$id; $i++){
    \DB::table('beds')->insert([
        'floor_id'=>$request->get('floor_id'),
        'room_id'=>$room->id,
        'beds'=>$i]);
}        
return back();
```

when i want in blade file then everytime pass first id so how to beds wise id pass in blade file to use modal popup

beds add propertly as i want but when i in blade file to open each modal for bed then everytime first id get so how to do it as beds wise id when i click modal popup

This is the blade
here is my blade file

```
  @for($i=1; $i<=$lists->no_of_beds; $i++)                                                                                                            
   <div class="col-lg-3">
     <div class="kt-widget24__info">  
      <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_assign-{{$lists->id}}">+ 
      </span>                                                                                                                                 
     </div>
    </div>
   @endfor
```

Comment: show your html ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my blade file:

```
   @for($i=1; $i<=$lists->no_of_beds; $i++)                                                                                                            
     <div class="col-lg-3">
       <div class="kt-widget24__info">  
         <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_assign-{{$lists->id}}">+ 
         </span>                                                                                                                                 
       </div>
     </div>
   @endfor
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry its very hard to understand what you are trying to do.
Unable to understand your english.
please elaborate your question so that we can answer.
**Questions regarding your code snippet are ** : 
1. can you please tell if it is savinf number of beds in DB. e.g if i entered number of beds as 4 does it enter them in DB ?  if it does(looks like it do) then what is the problem here ? What do you want to achieve in your Blade file.

Comment: Now after you have posted your blade file you are starting it as `@for` and closing it with `@foreach` ? it does'nt make any sense to me

Comment: please go through this https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#loops 
This may hep you.

Comment: please  check i post my question

Comment: @vandanmakwana  can you please paste `dd($lists)` in your controller after retrieving it from db  and show me the output.

Comment: original: array:8 [▼
    "id" => 9
    "floor_id" => 1
    "room" => "1"
    "bed_type" => "double bed"
    "no_of_beds" => "4"
    "status" => "assign"
    "created_at" => "2020-02-06 06:22:59"
    "updated_at" => "2020-02-06 06:22:59"
  ]

Comment: as it is not so much clear from your question i cannot say anything specific and concrete about it.

Comment: @vandanmakwana according to me your problem lies in here **`data-target="#modal_assign-{{$lists->id}}`** try passing it a hardcode number like `data-target="#modal_assign-1` and see what it do then

Comment: then display 1 but i want id wise modal popup